# Determine the Next SPListItem ID in a MOSS SPList?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, caml

I am trying to determine what the ID of the next list item to be created in a MOSS list will be.  Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks, MagicAndi

Comment: This is the sort of question that should make you rethink your approach.  Why do you need to know the future?  What do you need this value for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CAML query would determine the most likely ID to be generated next:

```
int iNextID = 1;

try
{
    using (SPSite objSite = new SPSite(sSiteUrl))
    {
        using (SPWeb objWeb = objSite.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPList objList = objWeb.Lists[sListName];

            SPQuery objQuery = new SPQuery();
            // objQuery.RowlImit = 1;
            objQuery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy><RowLimit>1</RowLimit>";
            objQuery.Folder = objList.RootFolder;

            // Execute the query against the list
            SPListItemCollection colItems = objList.GetItems(objQuery);

            if (colItems.Count > 0)
            {
                string sMaxID = colItems[0]["ID"].ToString();
                iNextID += int.Parse(sMaxID);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...
}

return iNextID;
```

However, this does not work for the case where the most recently generated list item (with ID N) is deleted, and we then use the above code to give the next ID - it will return N, when it should be N+1.

Comment: Yeah it also doesn't work if you delete all your items in the list, the code will return 1, even though internally is still keeping count

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link: http://snipplr.com/view/24210/next-splistitem-id-from-splist/, I have tried this solution and it does overcome the other shortcomings, it involves querying the WSS content DB which can be a little bit more expensive, but you could implement a hybrid solution, where you would query the DB ONLY if colItems.Count == 0 after the other logic.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be more sure you can create a listitem, record its ID, delete the list item and the next listitem will have ID+1. This should overcome the case where the last item was deleted.

Of course this is quite uqly.. but so is reading from the content database.

May I ask why you need it? Alternatively you can add a column to your list that contains a GUID so you can pre-generate ID's yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution to this problem.

The problem I had was related to versions:

```
var newItem = myList.Items.Add();
newItem["Title"] = "whatever";
newItem.Update();
newItem["MyProperty"] = "whatever" + newItem.ID;
newItem.Update();
```

I had versioning on my list but didn't want to create two different versions of my new item.
Solved it like this:

```
var newItem = myList.Items.Add();
newItem["Title"] = "whatever";
newItem.Update();
myList.EnableVersioning = false;
myList.Update();
newItem["MyProperty"] = "whatever" + newItem.ID;
newItem.Update();
myList.EnableVersioning = true;
myList.Update();
```

One might think that turning versioning off would erase all versions except the current but it doesn't.

This doesn't give you the next ID but might solve the underlying problem for someone.

Comment: Rather than turn off and on versioning, a better solution is to call newItem.SystemUpdate(false) to update the item without triggering a new version. Hope this helps!